# How to make pop up using 'ng_show'?

Tags: angularjs, popup

How to make pop-up, when `ng-click="show()"` ?

Here's my code:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="show()">Details</button>
<p ng-show="showThis">Nama : {{a.nama}} </br>
                    Alamat: {{a.alamat}} </br>
                    Telp: {{a.telp}}  </br>
                    Email{{a.email}}                                        
                                </p>

$scope.show = function() {
    this.showThis = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$scope.show = function () {
    $scope.showThis = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check the click i used in the html code.

- **Controller** 
  `$Scope.showThis = false;`
- **HTML** 
  `<button type="button" ng-click="showThis = !showThis">Details</button>
  <p ng-show="showThis">Nama : {{a.nama}} </br>
  Alamat: {{a.alamat}} </br>
  Telp: {{a.telp}}  </br>
  Email{{a.email}}</p>`